# Excel converting 0000 custom format to special formatting codigo Portugal

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, excel-formula

Just trying to apply custom formatting to my cell such that I always end up with a 4-digit number.
If I enter 12, the end result should be 0012. However, the format is being converted to special.

Ive looked it up and tried stuff like [$]0000 and 0000;0000;0000;@ which worked as display but when I upload the file into my ASP.NET app, the 0s are being removed.

I tried the same thing with custom 0000000 but strangely, this one is working fine and good values with leading are uploaded

Comment: The cell format is just how the cell displays the underlying value.  The underlying value will 12, but is displayed as 0012.  Try using a formula to reference your original number `=TEXT(A1,"0000")`.  The cell will be formatted as text, but will retain the leading 0's.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38820000/4961700

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, The formula will show up when I input data in the cell. Cant this be done using custom formatting?

Comment: Custom formats will not affect the cell **contents** and it would seem likely that that is what your app is reading.

Comment: @Rory, but the 0s are being removed. If value is 0012 using the above "custom formats", the 0s are being removed. Only 12 is uploaded :/

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Custom formats only affect what is **displayed** in Excel (unless you save the workbook as a csv file). Anything that reads the cell **value**, will read 12 not 0012.

Comment: @Rory, but I applied custom formating as 0000000. And i uploaded a value such as 551, it got uploaded as 0000551. How to do the same for 4 digits?

Comment: @SolarMike, no not the same

Comment: I question myself why you want to store the string as a number, but display with leading 0's. Why not use Darren Bartrup's solution and afterwards copy and paste as value?

Comment: @P.b, I need the user to use the excel and fill in the data. I need that formatting over a column. Users will see formula if I use it. That is why I wanna use custom formatting

Comment: You could put the formula on a hidden sheet and upload the data from that?

Comment: **How** is the data uploaded?